# what is this command doing in batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-server-2008, sftp, command-line

I have this command in .batch file.

Can someone explain me what it is doing?

`ftp -d -s:c:/somefolder/file_xfer/ftpcmds.txt > c:/somefolder/file_xfer/xfer_prt.txt`

I need to know because I am asked to change ftp to SFTP but I do not find SFTP in windows.

I found PSFTP [from putty](http://java.sg/how-to-sftp-from-windows-command-prompt-using-psftp/)

Any feedback will be appreciated

**Edit** 
xfer_prt file has following content

```
open SERVERNAME

USER username

PASS passwordhere
prompt
cd /somedir/somedir2
CWD /somedir/somedir2
mput C:\somedir2\*
PORT ##,##,##,##,###,### (## some numbers I don't want to share.
STOR somefile.html
STOR Runner.flag
quit
QUIT
```

Comment: Did you try `ftp /?` to see what the switches mean?  `-d` prints extra debugging information, `-s:path\to\ftpcmds.txt` is a script telling `ftp` where to connect and what to do after connecting, and `> path\to\xfer_prt.txt` redirects the output of `ftp` from the console to a text log.

Comment: I did `ftp /?` I understood `-d` but when it did `-s` but I don't understand where it is ftping to since it has path to local C:/ drive why use ftp ?

Comment: You should post contents of c:/somefolder/file_xfer/ftpcmds.txt, because that's what matters. The file should contain FTP commands to connect, transfers, etc...

Comment: Thanks, I saw tht too, I after I follow the linking and the process of calling this ftp. it is opening someserver and logs in with user and pass.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Please see edit of `xfer_prt.txt` posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-s` parameter accepts a path to a local file that contains *commands* that will be passed one at a time to the `ftp` programme.  In your case, the file `ftpcmds.txt` likely starts with something like this:

```
open ftp.domain.com
username
password
put file.txt
...
quit
```

Windows does not have a built-in `sftp` client, so you will need to find a third-party client, but I would guess they would have a similar command-line feature.  That will of course be completely dependent on the particular `sftp` app you choose.

Comment: Thanks Nate, that's what exactly is in that ftpcmds file, but the problem is sometimes ftp processes get stuck in windows server. it doesn't close as it should itself meaning gets hung in task manager any solution for this?

Comment: The commands that get passed in to `ftp` from the text file are static and can't "adapt" based on whether there are errors during the transfer.  So it's certainly easy to imagine it could get hung up, where `ftp` is expecting more commands but the calling process doesn't realize it. To figure out what's causing the hangup, you'll have to find a scenario that reproduces the problem every time, and then issue the commands manually instead of from the text file, and see what errors or unexpected results occur.